# jQuery appending attribute content

Tags: jquery

I am creating a system of displaying link information in an interactive way using html attributes, and jQuery to move some of the HTML around. I am stuck trying to append a title attribute to a div. I've never done this with an attribute and am hitting some walls.

It's hard to explain, but you will see what I am after when you see the JS.
http://jsfiddle.net/KvAwa/

thx for any help in advance

The HTML

```
<div id="navtool">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="1">
            <a href="location1.html" title="this is the decription1">This is the link1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="2">
            <a href="location2.html" title="this is the decription2">This is the link2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="3">
            <a href="location3.html" title="this is the decription3">This is the link3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev nav">prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next nav">next</a>
<div id="linkdesciption"></div>
<a href="#" id="execute">Execute link</a>​
```

The JS

```
// Cycles Menu   
$('#menu > li:first').addClass('active');
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.active').next().addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');        
    $('#menu > li:last').after($('#menu > li:first'));
});
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('.active').prev().addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    $('#menu > li:first').before($('#menu > li:last'));
});

// Collects the link  
var executeLink = $('#menu > li.active > a').attr("href");
$('#execute').attr("href", executeLink); 
$('#execute').click(function(){
   alert(executeLink);
});

// Collects title and inject into description
$('.nav').click(function(){
    var description = $('.active > a').attr('title'); 
    $(description).appendTo('#linkdesciption');
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and markup. Try to create a more minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* the relevant part of that code is:

```
$('.nav').click(function(){
    var description = $('.active > a').attr('title'); 
    $(description).appendTo('#linkdesciption');
});
```

You want to turn that around:

```
$('.nav').click(function(){
    var description = $('.active > a').attr('title'); 
    $('#linkdesciption').append(description);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvAwa/2/)

Or if you want to *replace* the previous link title with the new one, use `html` or `text` rather than `append`:

```
$('.nav').click(function(){
    var description = $('.active > a').attr('title'); 
    $('#linkdesciption').text(description);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvAwa/3/)

Comment: YES! this is exactly what I am after.

Comment: @TJ how can I get it to display the title on load before the click. using the variable twice messes it up a little.

Comment: @patrick: You mean on initial load? You just use a selector that will select the link you want to get the title from, and use the code above to get the title and set it in the description div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle if I understood it correctly:
http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/KvAwa/1/

Comment: Applies to answers, too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question